# Regular Expression to validate empty fields

Tags: regex

I have a form that use a regular expression that validate decimals and natural numbers, but I have a problem, this doesn't validate empty fields. My expression regular is this :

```
"^([0-9])+\.[0-9]|[0-9]$"
```

what can I do in order to this regular expression validate empty fields? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use this regular expression to handle both number(only positive) and empty.

```
^(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)?$
```

Explanation of the regex is:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Thanks guys,

I proved all of your suggestions but It not resolved my problem at all, 
still allow to enter empty fields, I maybe not explain very well, 
I would like that my regular expression does not permit to register empty fields.

Comment: @Jeason you are right, you didn't explain it well. We got you mean to allow empty and that caused the problem. So, the fix is just remove the `?` before the `$`. Finally it will be `^(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)$` and it will not allow any empty.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
"^(?:([0-9])+\.[0-9]*|[0-9]|)$"
```

This regex contains an additional possibility of no characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
^([0-9]+\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*)$
```

This:

- fixes the problem that only exactly 1 digit was accepted after the decimal dot,
- fixes the problem you had that you only accepted natural numbers of a single digit,
- fixes the problem that the beginning and end of the field were not matched in both cases,
- allows 0 digits, which is an empty field.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,

I proved all of your suggestions but It not resolved my problem at all, 
still allow to enter empty fields, I maybe not explain very well, 
I would like that my regular expression does not permit to register empty fields.