# How to bypass / validate required input field by faking (or empty) content?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, regex, osticket

I have a problem with a system called **[OSTicket](http://osticket.com/)**. You simply can't remove the "required" status of the input field (email) when you are adding a new user to your database. That's because the dynamic form / input fields are set with **Ajax** and we can't access those files. Therefore, I have to get a *workaround* for this. I tried using **Javacript / jQuery** so that it puts a *default value* in to the HTML, but that didn't work. With other words: I do not have access to the form that I want to edit, therefore I have to manipulate it on a different way. [This is a known issue btw; OSTicket works this way.](http://osticket.com/forum/discussion/76493/disable-require-email)

Anyhow, in the backend, I can change the validator from email to for example: **regex** field. So I thought: maybe I can check the field by using a regular expression and checking whether the field is empty... well: no result. If you submit the form, it still gives you the error *"field is required, please fill in"*.

When I check the `Ajax` response, I see this: http:// mydomainname.com /scp/ajax.php/users/lookup/form

Problem: ajax.php exists, but there is no /users/lookup/form. And when you check ajax.php, it's written like this:

```
url('^/orgs', patterns('ajax.orgs.php:OrgsAjaxAPI')....
```

So to wrap it up... I tried:

- [Changing the HTML (removing the required status)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937113/setting-an-html-text-input-boxs-default-value-revert-the-value-when-clicking)
- [Manipulating the DOM via jQuery / Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517366/change-form-values-after-submit-button-pressed)
- [Changing the field from an email field to a regex field and checking if empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581085/regular-expression-to-validate-empty-fields)

Now, I think that I have to do something to manipulate the Ajax call (if possible), but I don't know where to start. What is the best way to do this?

**I mean, is there a chance I can bypass a required field, without filling in something or is there any other way I can remove the required status of that field after the form has been loaded and I submit the form?**

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing any relevant code but to submit the form by removing attribute required, you could use in submit handler of `form`: `$('[type=email]').prop('required', false);`

Comment: The problem is that I can't find the submit handler of this form @A.Wolff. I mean, it all happens in an Ajax file. If I check the response, it gives me this form: ..../scp/ajax.php/users/lookup/form  .Well. Ajax.php exists indeed, but there is no /users/lookup/form anywhere in the code so I can't trace it.

Comment: Isn't is [open source](https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket-1.8)? So you could download it and do a grep for the action call?